# Why and how to stop view animation not working?

Tags: animation

I have been working on a animation of a penguin rocket, but when I click "view animation" it will play through around 1 fifth of the animation then stop and repeat it again, only to stop at the same point and repeat the cycle. I can provide videos and images if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
MaxWasHere.

Comment: Some of your frames may be cut off, as in, you've only enabled a certain amount of frames to play in your render settings, but the animation extends beyond that range.

Comment: how can I change the amount of frames in the render settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this first picture, I have three keyframes, but only two will play because I have my *end frame* set to 24.

[image]

To fix that, go to *Properties Editor* > *Output* tab.

[image]

Go in the *Frame Range* panel.

[image]

Change the *frame end* from 24 to 100 or whatever end frame number you want.

[image]

Now the animation plays beyond the original 24 frame.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it works now.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: For future users unexperienced with animation who might come across this answer, it is probably better to write "three keyframes" at the beginning, "three frames" might confuse people when you then go on talking about frame rate and frame range which are about the animation frames in general and not specifically about keyframes. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The frame rate and end frame are two very different things. The end frame is when your timeline ends. The frame rate is how fast to play the frames (using a frames-per-second value). I fixed the answer to use the right vocabulary, and also added a bit more written UI description so that visually impaired people or slow network can use your answer without the screenshots.